# Angular2 rc.4 upgrade breaks test - platformStrategy.getBaseHref is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular, jasmine, ngrx

I upgraded my Angular2 app to Release Candidate 4 and since then I have had to re-engineer some of my tests due to items being introduced or depreciated with the new release candidate version. However a massive amount of my tests now fail and I'm not sure why but I am  dogged with the following error and I am unsure why, this must occur for 50% of my tests

```
[2]     Error: EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Router! (BreadcrumbComponent -> Router).
[2]     ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: platformStrategy.getBaseHref is not a function
```

So, I assume something is wrong or there is a problem with "@ngrx/router": "^1.0.0-beta.1" but I could be wrong. So my tests look something like this... (I've tried to reduce this just to give an idea of what I am doing).

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-test',
    template: '<my-breadcrumb></my-breadcrumb>',
    directives: [NavigationComponent]
})
class NavigationComponentSelectorTestComponent {}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-dummy',
    template: 'dummy'
})
class DummyComponent {}

const routes: DisplayRoutes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        display: 'Home',
        component: DummyComponent
    }, {
        path: '/path1',
        display: 'Path1',
        component: DummyComponent
    }, {
        path: '/path2',
        display: 'Path2',
        component: DummyComponent,
        index: {
            component: DummyComponent
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '/:id',
                component: DummyComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];

class MockContentService {
    public getContentMock: SinonStub = stub();
    getContent(key: string):Observable<Card[]> {
        return this.getContentMock(key);
    }
}

// actual tests...
describe('Component: NavigationComponent', () => {

    beforeEach(() => addProviders([
        provideRouter(routes, SpyLocation),
        NavigationComponent,
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' },
        {provide: ContentService, useClass: MockContentService}
    ]));

    it('should provide injectable component', inject([NavigationComponent], (component: NavigationComponent) => {

        assertThat(component, is(defined()));
    }));
});
```

Everything was okay before the upgrade. Has anyone had a similar problem with `platformStrategy.getBaseHref is not a function`? Once again I am using Angular2 rc4, "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2" and   "@ngrx/router": "^1.0.0-beta.1". Thanks in advance.

**** UPDATE ****

I can't be sure but I think the problem is coming from `addProviders([])`, as I have the error in my IDE - 'Cannot resolve symbol for addProviders' however it is in my node modules and I am importing it correctly!

```
import {
    it,
    describe,
    xdescribe,
    beforeEach,
    addProviders,
    async,
    inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. 
Altho it probably won't solve your problem, it may help to know, that for me, as long as I don't inject 'Location', the error does not occur.
But this is obviously only a temporary work around.